# How do I rename a solution-level folder in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and TFS Express.  I have the top level collection `192.168.100.100\Collection`; under it I have a project for each program; under those I have the solution folders.  So in the project folder `FooBarBaz` I have the solution `OldName`.  (I'd rather not post screen shots of the folder tree, but I can rig up an ASCII art depiction if needed.)

I want to rename the folder OldName to NewName.  I have already successfully renamed the solution itself and checked that in.  I have also successfully changed my local mapping from `~/Projects/OldName` to `~/Projects/NewName`.

In MSVS Source Code Explorer, when I right-click on `OldName` the context menu options Rename and Move are both greyed out.

How do I rename the folder in TFS?  I am the team's TFS admin so I can use the web-based settings and I can also use the TFS control panel on the host system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click on the folder name in the *left* panel.

Also, you must have those folders mapped into your current workspace.

Comment: Do you mean I need to map the collection `FooBarBaz` first?  If so, that would explain why the context menu for the folder panel still has Rename and Move greyed out.

Comment: Yes, you can only make changes to mapped folders.

Comment: I mapped the collection, non-recursive (as the solution folder is already mapped).  I restarted MSVS.  Rename is still greyed out.

Comment: So I re-mapped the collection **recursively**.  Now it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-step assumption: Create local folder with solution and project under it and added solution to TFS.  TFS now has a path in TFS pointing to a TFS folder that contains your added solution.  This location is bound to the location on your local machine that is likely out of sync with the path structure represented in Source Control Explorer.

You want to rename the folder in TFS that holds your solution.  When I right-click in Source Control Explorer, “Rename” is grayed out.  It appears that TFS wants the TFS path to match your local path structure.

In order to rename the TFS folder I had to:

1. Check everything in
2. Remove binding to source control
3. Do a get latest - TFS assumes structure inherited binding - so whatever the folder is named and where it is in the TFS path structure, the get latest will create a local folder to hold the code.
4. Now, right click on the folder and do a rename in Source Control Explorer.
5. TFS and your local workspace are now in sync.  If you now go and rename the TFS folder that contains your solution, the next time you open the solution, your local folder name will be automatically changed to match TFS.

Of course, don’t forget to go back later - after VS has released the lock, and delete your old/first/”no longer bound to TFS” version of the local solution folder.

I hope this helps someone else.